# Problem with constructing a smooth function with given properties

Tags: analysis

I wish to construct a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ of class $C^\infty (\mathbb R)$ with the folowing properties:

$f(x)=0$ for $|x|\leq 1$

$f(x)=x$ for $|x| \geq 2$,

$|f(x)| \leq |x|$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Define "smooth" (e.g., differentiable for all values of $x$, at least once).

Comment: Well, the question did say to construct a function in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, so we can probably assume smooth = infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x\leq 0,\\
\exp \left(-1/x\right) & 0<x.
\end{cases}
$$
The function $g(x)=f(x)f(1-x)$ is smooth. Also, it is non-zero for $x=1/2$ but vanishes when $x<0$ or $x>1$. Consider the function
$$
F(x)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)dt}{\int g(t)dt}.
$$

Comment: This function $f$ is not continuous at $1$.

Comment: Whoops, fixed that.